# CSS: vertical scrollbar won't appear when resizing the window, position: absolute

Tags: html, css, position, css-position, absolute

http://lymieer.net/janit/

When I resize the window, only the horizontal scrollbar appears. Other material that don't fit in the window (vertically) anymore, just "disappears" at the top of the window, acting like a background-image. How can I make it work right? I have tried everything I know and always something goes wrong somehow (if I get the scrollbar thing work, something else didn't). The page should look like these:

http://i42.photobucket.com/albums/e334/kermakavio/jani.jpg

**CSS:**

```
body {
    background-color: black;
    overflow: scroll;
    }

header {
    left: 400px;
    bottom: 640px;
    position: absolute;
    }

section {
    overflow: auto;
    bottom: 80px;
    left: 280px;
    width: 600px;
    height: 400px;
    position: absolute;
    }

footer {
    width: 600px; 
    height: 10px;
    bottom: 10px;
    left: 280px;
    position: absolute;
    }

.tausta {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    }
```

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <title>Jani Talonen</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="jani.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- sivun sisältö -->
        <img src="Tausta.jpg" class="tausta" />
        <header><img src="otsikko.png" /></header>

        <section>Lavasterakentajan työtehtävät

Lavasterakentaja on käytännön tekijä. Hän toimii lavastajan tai muun suunnittelijan antamien ohjeiden mukaan ja rakentaa lavasteita teatteriin, televisioon tai elokuviin. Lavasterakentaja osaa rakentaa erilaisia näyttelyosastoja esimerkiksi messuille, konferensseihin ja museoihin.
<br /><br />
Lavasterakentajalla on visuaalista silmää ja taitoa hahmottaa tilaa. Toimivien ratkaisujen löytäminen edellyttää luovuutta, ideointikykyä ja kekseliäisyyttä. Lavasterakantaja valmistaa lavasteita lähes mitä tahansa materiaalista – puusta, metallista, muovista. Hän työstää materiaaleja maalaten, rakentaen, tapetoiden ja osaa purkaa, pystyttää ja korjata lavasteita. 
<br /><br />
Lavasterakentaja voi työskennellä somistajana, teattereiden lavastepajoissa tai elokuvia ja tv-tuotantoja tekevissä tuotantoyhtiöissä. Lavastustyö ostetaan useasti ulkopuolisena freelancer-työnä.
Lisätietoa lavasterakentajan koulutuksesta
<br /><br />
Lisää tietoa Pohjois-Karjalan ammattiopisto Outokummun lavasterakentajan koulutuksesta saat täyttämällä sivun alareunassa olevan yhteydenottopyynnön, jolloin Pohjois-Karjalan ammattiopisto Outokumpu vastaa kysymyksiisi.
        </section>
        <footer>(c) Anni Pihlaja 2015</footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is because you got .tausta bottom property set to zero, which will pin your image to the bottom of the viewport.

Comment: PS. Remember to ask clear question, like "why" or "what is causing such behaviour"

Comment: I edited my post, hope it's now a little bit more clear.

Answer (score 1):

This happens because your image tausta.jpg has absolute property with bottom: 0px;
You should set your image in Css with background-image property instead.

Moreover you shouldn't use position:absolute on every elements.

Comment: If I remember right, when I set it in css with background-image, I wasn't able to get the background in the bottom of the page. There was always some empty space between the background and the border of the window. Anyway, that changing the background as image was my last try to get the whole thing work, but it sucks still, but the other way.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have enough elements on the page for `<body>` to have enough height. Everything is positioned absolutely. When an element is positioned in that way, and has a set width and height, it'll either have an inner scroll, the content will overflow, or be hidden. In the event you resize your browser window, things disappear because of how they were positioned.

Set the image as the background using CSS's `background-image` property.

Even more important than that, stop using `position: absolute` on every element. What you're trying to do is not a great idea in terms of how the code is structured, and how the page will re-flow across different browser heights and widths.